# Solr facet with additional metadata

Tags: solr

Is it possible to use additional metadata fields when using Solr facets? I would like to aggregate one attribute by counting them and desplaying the related group as additional metadata field.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/gitIndex/select?indent=on&q=*:*&rows=0&wt=json&
        json.facet={
            Repository_s: {
                type: terms,
                field: Repository_s,
                limit: 10,
                facet: {
                    x:"count()"
                }
            }
        }
```

The result should look like this:

```
...
      "facets":{
        "count":1354013,
        "<name of attribute>":{
          "buckets":[{
              "val":"<value of attribute>",
              "count":173997,
              "<metadata_field>":<value of metadata_field>},
...
```

Comment: Is the metadata_field-value identical over all documents in the facet? Or are you looking for a pivot facet?

Comment: Yes, the metadata_field is identical over all documents. Let me give one example. I would like to know the population in London and the related country. The city is divided into districts and i would summarize them. In addition, the name of the country is used as metadata field.  The result would be: {"city": "London", "population": 8000000, "country": "England"  }

Comment: I think you'll have to use facet pivot's for that - you'll get the result, and a sub-facet with England as the key and the same count. For the JSON API this is [done by adding another facet: entry under the existing facet](http://yonik.com/solr-subfacets/).

Comment: Thanks for the helpful link. The pivot function with nested sub-facets worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to use [facet pivots](http://yonik.com/solr-subfacets/) - it'll get you any values in a secondary field under each facet, and if the value is unique for the set of documents, it'll just be a single value.

The [reference guide has the syntax for non-json facets](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceting#Faceting-Pivot(DecisionTree)Faceting).